# SSL authentication Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

We're trying to set up our rails app to work with SSL.  We have it running on passenger on an Apache server.   I've set  config.force_ssl = true in environments/production.rb.  I now get the following error:

```
An error occurred during a connection to blah.8081

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

I'm told our server is set up with a certificate.  Is there another step required, such as some configuration in the server configuration file?  Do I 'register' this app somewhere, or something? I'm just learning about ssl.  Thanks

Comment: When I set up my app with an ssl cert, all I had to do on the rails side was set `config.force_ssl = true`.  Sounds like its a server config issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We needed to set up the correct port in the httpd.conf (apache configuration) file.  I believe SSL defaults to 443 or something. Here a snippet of our working .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
  ServerName dev.mysite.com:8081
    SSLEngine on
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/some_file
    SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/some_file_2
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/dev.mysite.com/webapps/
        RackBaseURI /testapp/current
        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/dev.mysite.com/webapps/testapp/current>
                AllowOverride all
                Allow from all
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```